# How to run a .sql file as part of a MySQL Workbench 6.2 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2 [Windows7] and I want to create a script with all my steps. Among the steps, I have a series of .sql files stored from on my computer that create and populate tables. 
I want to run these files from the query tab but every time I use this command:

source C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/sampdb/create_president.sql;

I get an  Error 1064, which says

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> source
>   C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/sampdb/create_president.sql at line 1 "

[image: MySQL nested script nightmare]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I refer to a .sql file within a MySQL Workbench script?

What code should I use in the MySQL Workbench instead of `source`? I have tried `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/sampdb/create_president.sql';` but it didn't work either. Any idea what can be wrong?

*Just for additional information, create_president.sql contains the following code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS president;
#@ _CREATE_TABLE_
CREATE TABLE president
(
  last_name  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  suffix     VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  city       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  state      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  birth      DATE NOT NULL,
  death      DATE NULL
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `source` command is a pure (command line) client specific command which MySQL Workbench does not support. Just load the sql file to run it.

**Update** (after you edited your question)

Your SQL file contains DDL. `LOAD DATA INFILE` however only imports DML. There's no replacement for the MySQL commandline client's `SOURCE` command. Support for that in MySQL Workbench is however on our todo list.

Comment: Thanks Mike, sorry if the question is too basic, I am self-learning. 
I am trying the following but it is not working either. Can you spot what's wrong with it?: 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:/Users/[username]/Desktop/sampdb/create_president.sql'; 

That create_president.sql has the following code:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS president;
#@ _CREATE_TABLE_
CREATE TABLE president
(
  last_name  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  suffix     VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  city       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  state      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  birth      DATE NOT NULL,
  death      DATE NULL
);

Comment: This is difficult to read in the comment. Either update your question here or open a new one, where we can take a look.

Answer (score 5):

You can run scripts on **MySqlWorkBench** as follows:

From the file menu, Select "Run SQL Script".

[image]

Then, In the popup window, Open the script from your machine.

[image]

Then Select the schema name which you are going to execute this script. (Previously i created the schema using the command "create database REGISTRY_LOCAL1;")

[image]

Then execute the script.

[image]