# MySQL workbench 6.3 CE: can't run the empolyee sample database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have recently downloaded and unzipped the [employee sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html) for MySQL. I was instructed to run the `employee.sql` file to load the database, but it simply didn't run on my Workbench editor.

I was connecting to the localhost server. The part of `employee.sql` that couldn't run was as follows:

```
-- Before this part, a complete database with several tables have already been defined.

SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

According to the error message raised, the `source` command was out of place here. These lines I think were intended to read data from the dump files into our already defined "frames", so they couldn't be omitted. However, since they couldn't run on the Workbench editor, I have to figure out another way to get it to run. It seems that we could also run SQL scripts on `MySQL Shell` or the command lines, but that would be too troublesome and what's more I don't want to lose the elegant Workbench GUI. So what can I do?

My goal is just to practice a bit on the sample database, I'm an absolute beginner on Databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `employee.sql` from shell as `source` is a MySQL shell command and is not available through workbench. The link you posted has the steps to install through shell which are easy to follow.

This question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318216/how-to-run-a-sql-file-as-part-of-a-mysql-workbench-6-2-query).

Comment: I tried both the java script mode and the sql mode and neither worked.

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: win10 64 bit up to date. The command looked like `mysql-sql >  -u root -p filepath` (in sql mode, if in js mode the prompt would be `mysql-js`), and the error message was "not connected". But the localhost server was indeed running, since it was active on Workbench in the meantime.

Comment: I did this. Running CMD/PS in privileged mode. Then `cd` to the directory where the zip you downloaded was extracted. Then `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -p -t employee.sql`